# Query for records that have a certain elements in an array

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

So I am trying to search for documents that have any of the given tags (i.e. "a", "b", or "c").

The MongoDB query is:

```
db.my_collection.find({ "tags" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$in" : ["a", "b", "c"] } } })
```

This works just fine (tags is a document field which is an array of tags for the document). Now the problem is when I try to build this query using SpringData Query and Criteria objects.

```
List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Criteria inTags = new Criteria().in(tags);
Criteria where = Criteria.where("tags").elemMatch(inTags);
Query query = new Query(where);
System.out.println(query);
```

The output of this is:

```
Query: { "tags" : { "$elemMatch" : { }}}, Fields: null, Sort: null
```

Which of course does not end up working for me. Does anyone know how to make this work with SpringData query/criteria. I am not interested in ugly work-arounds or using the MongoDB Java driver directly - I can do that. I want to know if there is any way to do this right with the SpringData classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$elemMatch` in a non-standard way here as it's meant to match multiple fields within a single array element.  Use a query like this instead:

```
db.my_collection.find({ "tags": "$in": ["a", "b", "c"] })
```

That should be easier to get working in SpringData.

Comment: Probably a stray click - sorry.